# Sharepoint Template page with webparts

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, template

I am working in SharePoint Online (Sub-site) and we have 10 pages with custom web parts (for example a Photo library) and custom content (text). Each page consists of 2 'default' web parts with two lists with an XSL template, for now I have added these web parts to one page, and copied that page 10 times in SharePoint Designer, in SharePoint Designer when copying a page the web parts will be copied too. This is not the case if I copy the page online. This is working fine.

Here comes the problem, maintenance costs a lot of time. For example, when the user wants to change the background color of a default web part I have to change it for each page. Another situation is when the user wants to add a default webpart, I have to do this 10 times.

What is the best way to solve this? In SharePoint, is it possible to have a custom template with default web parts and a possibility to add other web parts later by the user?

What's the way to go for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a page layout, add web parts in this layout and create page using this page layout.

If user need to update any of the webpart, he just need to update the page layout and changes will reflect for all the pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this tomorrow. I will let you know if it works.